# Inconsistent accessibility Error in Program

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently trying to C# asp.net and this was one of my old labs that I never attended and I'm looking for help on it.

Basically I want to be able to store details of the person I input onto a webpage and then bring them up in the About page.

I keep getting the error:

```
 Error 1: Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Lab5.Person>' is less accessible than field 'Lab5._Default.PresentPerson'
```

My code:

```
Class Person:
{
    class Person
    {
        string age;
        string name;
        string dob;
        string telNo;
        string gender;
        string address;

        public string Age 
        { 
            get { return age; } 
            set { age = value; } 
        }
        public string Name 
        { 
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; } 
        }
        public string DOB 
        { 
            get { return dob; } 
            set { dob = value; } 
        }
        public string TelNo 
        { 
            get { return telNo; } 
            set { telNo = value; } 
        }
        public string Gender 
        { 
            get { return gender; } 
            set { gender = value; } 
        }
        public string Address 
        { 
            get { return address; } 
            set { address = value; } 
        }

        public string enterPerson;

        public Person(string name, string age, string dob, string telNo, string gender, string address)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            DOB = dob;
            TelNo = telNo;
            Gender = gender;
            Address = address;
        }

        public string PresentPerson()
        {
            return enterPerson = "Name: " + Name + "\n" + "Age: " + Age + "\n" +  "Date of Birth: "
            + DOB + "\n" + "Telephone Number: " + TelNo + "\n" + "Gender: " + Gender + "\n" + "Address: "
            + Address;
        }
    }
  }
```

Code behind the Default page:

```
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public static IList<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Write("You have successfully added a Person!");

            personList.Add(new Person(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text,
            TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, DropDownList1.Text, TextBox5.Text));
            Session["Person"] = personList;

        }
    }
}
```

and code in the About page:

```
{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["PersonList"] != null)
            {
                IList<Person> personList = (List<Person>)Session["PersonList"];
                foreach (Person p in personList)
                {
                    Response.Write(string.Format("Name :{0} and Age :{1}, DOB :{2}, TelNo, :{3}, Gender :{4}, Address :{5} ", p.Name, p.Age, p.DOB, p.TelNo, p.Gender, p.Address));
                    Response.Write("<br/>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that there's probably a load of issues, but I am new to C#!

Answer (score 2):

Your `_Default` page has a list of `Person` field.  `Person` is *internal*, but `_Default` is *public*.

This is the inconsistency - clients of `_Default` would have access to these `Person` objects when they shouldn't.  To fix, make `Person` *public*:

```
public class Person
{
    ....
```

You could, alternatively, make the field *internal* or *private*.

```
private static IList<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `class Person` to `public class Person`

If something is public like the _Default class in your example every public thing on it also needs to be public. You can't have a public thing that is in fact private.

Comment: Thanks - I was very silly in thinking that the error meant something more when it actually wasn't!

Comment: Don't worry everyone has one made this mistake sometime